# Characteristic subgroups of extra-special p-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a extra-special $p$-group of order $p^{1+2r}$ with exponent $p$ (p odd). I want to know  if $G$ has only $3$ characteristic subgroups?

Background: From [2],  if $G$ is extra-special $5$-group of order $5^5$ with exponent $5^2$, then $G$ has more than $3$ characteristic subgroup. How about the exponent of the extraspecial $p$-group is $p$?

There are some references about this topic.
[1]. D.R. Taunt, Finite groups having unique proper characteristic subgroups I, Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 51 (1955) 25–36.
[2]. S.P. Glasby, P.P. Pálfyb, Csaba Schneider p-groups having a unique proper non-trivial characteristic subgroup Journal of Algebra 348 (2011) 85–109

Comment: The extra-special group is a central power $H^n/Z$ of the Heisenberg group $H$ (of exponent $p$). Consider the subgroup $U$ of $H^n$ consisting of all constant functions (i.e. vectors where all coordinates are equal). Is the image of $U$ in $H^n/Z$ characteristic?

Comment: @Mark: Thanks Mark. But I have to say that I am not familiar with the Heisenberg group. I know the extra-special p-group in the way of  abstract group theory. I don't know how to do it in your way.

Comment: It is easy to check that the original question has a positive answer iff the action of $Out(G)$ on the vector space $G/Z$ over $\mathbf{Z}/p$ is irreducible.


Comment: [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_special_group) for background and definition of extraspecial groups

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An extraspecial $p$-group of exponent $p$ contains exactly three characteristic subgroups, $1$, $G$ and the center of $G$.

Let $Z$ be the center of $G$ (so $Z=[G,G]=\Phi(G)$).  The elementary abelian group $G/Z$ is a vector space of dimension $2r$ over the field of order $p$.  The commutator map on $G$ induces a nondegenerate alternating bilinear form on $G/Z$.  As shown in a paper of D. L. Winter in the Rocky Mountain Journal (1972), $Aut(G)$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $p-1$ such that $H/Inn(G)$ is isomorphic to the full stabilizer of the given form (this does not hold if $G$ does not have exponent $p$).  Since this stabilizer is irreducible on $G/Z$, no characteristic subgroup of $G$ (other than $G$) strictly contains $Z$.  Now assume for contradiction that $G$ has some nontrivial proper characteristic subgroup $X$ that does not contain $Z$.  Then $XZ$ is characteristic in $G$ and strictly contains $Z$, which forces $XZ=G$.  Now $X$ is maximal in $G$.  However, this forces $Z=\Phi(G)\leq X$, a contradiction.

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated what you prove.

Comment: Did that and made a couple of other changes for clarity.

Comment: @John: good to see you here!

Comment: @John: Thanks for your answer. I am not familar with Symplectic group. Would you please give me a reference that $Sp(2n, p)$ is irreducible on $G/Z$?

Comment: In Section 20 of Aschbacher's "Finite Group Theory", you will find a proof of Witt's Lemma.  A consequence of this lemma is that $Sp(2n,p)$ is transitive on $1$-dimensional subspaces of $G/Z$, from which irreducibility follows immediately. You can learn a lot about the symplectic group and other classical groups from Section 22 of that book.

Comment: @John: Thanks very much! It is interesting that the result we discuss is not inclued in [2].

Comment: John: no nontrivial normal subgroup misses the center in a p- group. 

Comment: Steve - Yes, that is much better than what I said at the end of the proof.  Thanks.